# Why exception is not catching by `catch`?

Tags: haskell, exception

Why does not this catch exception of conversion `conv B3` ?!

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Catch as E
data A = A1|A2 deriving (Enum, Show)
data B = B1|B2|B3 deriving (Enum, Show)
conv b = safeConv
  where
    catchError e = Left e
    safeConv = (Right $ (toEnum $ fromEnum b :: A)) `E.catch` catchError
```

I got:

```
Right *** Exception: toEnum{A}: tag (2) is outside of enumeration's range (0,1)
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at xxx.hs:227:26 in main:Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell exceptions are somewhat different than, say, Java or C++: "true" exceptions work in `IO` monad, and then there is an imitation of exceptions via pure means, as in [`ExceptT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/transformers-0.5.2.0/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT).

The `toEnum` function throws the first kind - `IO` exceptions, - which cannot be caught in pure code. They fly out to the nearest `IO` place, which in your case is apparently GHCi.

In order to catch such exceptions, you first need to wrap the throwing expression in `IO` via [`Control.Exception.evaluate`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate). Then you can catch such exceptions with `catch`, or, if you just want to convert it to an `Either exception A` (as you seem to be doing), there is an app for that! - it's called [`try`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Exception.html#g:7).

Further, when using either `catch` or `try`, you need to specify the specific *type* of the exception you're trying to catch. But [it is possible to catch *all* exceptions](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Exception.html#g:4) regardless of type by using the existential type `SomeException`.

So, wrapping up all of that, we get this code:

```
import qualified Control.Exception as E

data A = A1|A2 deriving (Enum, Show)
data B = B1|B2|B3 deriving (Enum, Show)

conv :: Enum b => b -> IO (Either E.SomeException A)
conv b = E.try . E.evaluate . toEnum $ fromEnum b
```

**NOTE 1**: The type annotation on `conv` is necessary in order to specify `E.SomeException` as the type of exception to catch. Without it, GHC will complain that the type of exception is ambiguous.

**NOTE 2**: Because our type annotation on `conv` already specifies the target type `A`, the type annotation on `toEnum $ fromEnum b` is no longer necessary.

**NOTE 3**: I have replaced your import of `Control.Monad.Catch` with `Control.Exception`, because that's where `evaluate` and `SomeException` are.

Comment: I know it. My question was to stay pure. `error/ErrorCall` from `toEnum` keeps hidden IO and no way to see this in signatures, and type-checking is OK, but exception is leaking :) Good news. So, no way to make it without `IO` involving, right?

Comment: Yes, no way. In Haskell you can throw IO exceptions in pure code (via `error`), but not catch them. I share the frustration, but whatchagonnado :-)

Comment: But I don't understand in this case signature of `catch` from "exceptions" `catch :: Exception e => m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a`, and `m` can be `Either` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.8.3/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html). And no any `IO`. What am I missing?

Comment: I tried also "errors" package `catchEither`, result is the same. No `IO`, no catching :)

Comment: Yes, `Either` is an instance of `Monad`, and also an instance of `MonadError`, but that's all beside the point: being an instance of `Monad` or `MonadError` simply means to implement certain functions in a certain way. You can look at the way `catch` [is implemented for `Either`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/mtl-2.2.1/src/Control.Monad.Error.Class.html#line-107): it simply translates `Left` and `Right` into "error" and "normal" cases respectively. There is no magic there, nothing special is happening.

Comment: The `IO` monad, on the other hand, is "magic". It is a window from Haskell into the real world, and so there are certain things associated with it, which are impossible to reproduce in pure code.

Answer (score -1):

I'll leave it here if someone needs a solution. To keep function pure, conversion should be:

```
unsafeConvEnum :: (Enum a, Enum b) => a -> b
unsafeConvEnum = toEnum . fromEnum

convEnum :: (Enum a, Enum b) => a -> Maybe b
convEnum e = unsafePerformIO conv'
  where onError (_::SomeException) = pure Nothing
        conv' = (Just <$> evaluate (unsafeConvEnum e)) `catch` onError
```

No any IO :)